# Facebook contact pictures not updating

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

Some contact pictures from Facebook are never updating, while others are working fine. The "google" part of the account have no picture set, the one showing is an old Facebook picture.

This problem appears both in the contacts, and in the Facebook application itself when you look at the contact list. Visiting the contact's personal page shows the correct picture, though. The Messenger application for the Facebook messages is showing the correct pictures.

I've tried to clear the cache (not the "data") of the Facebook application, to no avail.

Vanilla Android 2.3.6 on an unrooted Nexus One.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest clearing the data. Also, are you sure that the contact is actually being synced by the facebook application. The facebook application may not think that the contact is the "same person" that you know that it is.

I would clear the data and reset up the syncing for the facebook app. There maybe something in there that is preventing the image to update. Maybe a corrupt image, or data.

Comment: Yes I'm sure they were correctly linked. I cleared the data yesterday and now they updated correctly, however of course I can't rule out the possibility for it to break again in future.